# How does &((myStruct *)0)->x returns the offset of member x in type myStruct?

Tags: c, embedded

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char y;
    unsigned short int x;
} myStruct;

void main(void) {
    unsigned char offset = &((myStruct *)0)->x;
    printf("Offset=%d\n", offset);
}
```

using this magical macro expression `&((myStruct*)0)->x` returns the offset of member `x` in `myStruct`! Can anyone help me understand how it is allocated memory? I google that and I find out that there's a pointer of type `myStruct` is created and holds address `0` then it calculated the address of the member `x` which will lead to the offset value. I don't understand how does the pointer point to address `0` ? how does the compiler do it? and is address `0` a virtual address loaded at run time (in main stack function) to do so? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It isn't allocated any memory. It simply calculates what the offset would be *if* the `struct` was located at address `0`, based on what the address of that member would be.

Comment: From the linux kernel (linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-43/include/linux/stddef.h):



 15 #undef offsetof                                                                 
 16 #ifdef __compiler_offsetof                                                      
 17 #define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER)  __compiler_offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER)               
 18 #else                                                                           
 19 #define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER)  ((size_t)&((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)                  
 20 #endif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone help me understand how it is allocated memory?

It is not allocated. No memory is taken and no pointer dereferencing here.

Compiler simply calculates the address of the member `x` and converts it to the integer.

Unsigned char is not a very good type to store offsets. C has special type for that. It is called `ptrdiff_t`.
I would rather

```
ptrdiff_t offset = (char *)&(((myStruct *)0)->x) - (char *)&((myStruct *)0);
```

or

```
#define MYOFFSET(st,n) ((char *)&(((st *)0)->x) - (char *)&((st *)0))

ptrdiff_t offset = MYOFFSET(myStruct, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory allocated in this case, it's just a fictitious construct.

When you say

```
   (myStruct*)0
```

this creates a pointer to an object located at exactly the zero, which is not wrong btw since in many architectures the zero address is 100% valid and usually home to control structures.

On x86 the "zero page" is described here:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/zero-page.html

So the "zero address" points to exactly "Text mode or frame buffer information (struct screen_info)" which can be seen here:

https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/uapi_2linux_2screen__info_8h_source.html

Getting back to the chase, then you have the `->x` which represents the location of the member and then `&` which takes the address of this given member which should be at exactly `AddressOfObject+Offset`.

As `AddressOfObject` is zero, then the expression is exactly equal to the offset of the member.

Comment: It does not create any pointers. I simply converts integer to the pointer type. Nothing is created here

Comment: Of course a pointer is created. That's what the cast is for.

Comment: Where this pointer is created? If you write `4` does it create integer?

Comment: Of course it does. It is called an rvalue.

Comment: `rvalue` does not have to an object. Nothing is created. It is simple integer constant. You cast it another type it also does not create anything. if you do `int x = 4;` , then you create integer

Comment: You are confusing lvalues and rvalues. Integers and pointers can be both lvalues and rvalues. You are saying that integers can only be lvalues which is far from true.